# sending doc file as an attachment on iPad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I want to send .doc file as an email attachment from my app programmatically.

Comment: Is this a preexisting .doc file, or a dynamically generated one?

Comment: i am creating it dynamically through my app

Answer (score 6):

Use -[MFMailComposeViewController addAttachmentData:] with a mimeType of "application/msword". For example:

```
- (void)displayComposerSheet {
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [picker setSubject:@"I'm attaching a word document!"];

    // Set up recipients
    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"first@example.com"]; 
    NSArray *ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second@example.com", @"third@example.com", nil]; 
    NSArray *bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"fourth@example.com"]; 

    [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
    [picker setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];  
    [picker setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];

    // Attach a doc to the email
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyDocument" ofType:@"doc"];
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"application/msword" fileName:@"MyDocument"];

    // Fill out the email body text
    NSString *emailBody = @"Please see the attached document.";
    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```

Comment: i am using this code only.only difference is that I am having .doc file in documents directory.this mail attachment opens on mac but not on ipad

Comment: By open, do you means, opens and in readable as a doc file, or opens as in is detected and can be saved into an app sandbox?