# Write .kml files in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, xcode4.2

I would like to know how can i write to a file within Application. The thing im trying to do here is, i am generating a KML (using class XMLWriter from https://github.com/skjolber/xswi).  I can log the KML, everythings fine, now what i have to do is, Same this KML to a .kml file, and then email it to some address.

Emailing is no problem, i wanted to know how to write this KML into a .kml file, and then retrieve it for emailing. Can someone help me with a code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_4_iPhone_Directory_Handling_and_File_I/O_%E2%80%93_A_Worked_Example) did it, more then help.. The Code for generating the .kml file:

```
NSFileManager *filemgr;
NSData *databuffer;
NSString *dataFile;
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;

filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
dataFile = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"datafile.kml"];
databuffer = [[xmlWriter toString] dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
[filemgr createFileAtPath: dataFile contents: databuffer attributes:nil];
```

then to retrieve it i used:

```
NSFileManager *filemgr;
NSString *dataFile;
NSData *databuffer;
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;

filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

// Identify the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

// Build the path to the data file
dataFile = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"datafile.kml"];
databuffer = [filemgr contentsAtPath: dataFile];
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you've got all your content into a string, if so you can proceed with saving it to .kml file with something like this:

```
 NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
                                                      NSUserDomainMask, YES);   
NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];     
NSString* fname = [tmp_FileName stringByAppendingFormat: @".kml" ]; 
NSString* filenameStr = [documentsDirectory
                          stringByAppendingPathComponent:fname];
[yourKMLString writeToFile: filenameStr atomically: YES];
```

Comment: I'm on my mobile, so I hadn't a way to test the code, let me know if u got any problem

Comment: Yeah i have got all the contents in the string.. btw how will i get the file to set it as attachment?
Thanks alot :)

Comment: well, it depends by what composer are you using, I've done this just once, so I'm not that much experienced, but you can give a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509618/sending-doc-file-as-an-attachment-on-ipad. here they send a .doc file, but if you change the mime type you can do the trick for kml as well. hope it helped!

Comment: This [tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_4_iPhone_Directory_Handling_and_File_I/O_%E2%80%93_A_Worked_Example) did it, more then help.. Thanks :)